# Strange minitest fixture association issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

I have a model that has an association like this:

`belongs_to :state_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "state_user_id"`

In the fixtures I have this:

**Model in question:**

```
one:
  state_user: administrator (User)
```

**Users:**

```
administrator:
  name_first: 'Joe'
  name_last: 'Administrator'
```

yet in my tests this association fails like this:

```
 test 'should have state user' do
   assert @transfer.state_user.present?
 end

 FAIL TransfersControllerTest#test_should_have_state_user (174.10s)
        Expected false to be truthy.
        test/controllers/transfers_controller_test.rb:64:in `block in <class:TransfersControllerTest>'
```

I have run into this before and my hack has been to do this and directly reference by the user id:

```
one:
  state_user_id: 99
  # state_user: administrator (User)

fixed:
  id: 99
  name_first: "Mary"
  name_last: "Fixed"
```

This test then passes but not ideal.  This code works fine in development and production - just fails in this particular case.  My only thought is I am missing something with the `belongs_to` declaration.

**UPDATE**

Added a bugbye break as suggested in the comments:

```
(byebug) @transfer.state_user
nil

(byebug) @transfer.state_user_id
924281465

(byebug) User.where(name_first: 'Joe')
#<User id: 417269330, name_first: "Joe", name_last: "Administrator">
```

I have run this again trying different users - same results.  It's almost like the user ids are being created a second time after they are set in the Transfer models etc.

On a side note I have other `belongs_to` users like this:

```
  belongs_to :state_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "state_user_id"

  # The user that created the transfer

  belongs_to :initiated_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "initiated_user_id"

  # The user that the transfer is assigned to

  belongs_to :user

  # The user that approves the transfer to proceed

  belongs_to :approval_user, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "approval_user_id"

  # The user that completed the transfer

  belongs_to :completed_user, class_name: :user, foreign_key: "complete_user_id"
```

and now only the last one throws this error:

```
Minitest::UnexpectedError:         ActiveRecord::Fixture::FixtureError: table "transfers" has no columns named "complete_user".
```

All of these `belongs_to` Users also return the wrong user accossiation.

Comment: I would put a 'byebug' in the run before the assertion and have a poke around, this will at least confirm your understanding of @transfer.  Does assert @transfer.status_user.nil? pass?

Comment: Updated the question - very strange.

Answer (score 1):

What a crazy issue ‍♂️

I stumbled across this old post:

https://brandonhilkert.com/blog/7-reasons-why-im-sticking-with-minitest-and-fixtures-in-rails/

From that I realized that I didn't need to specify `(User)` in my fixtures as they are not polymorphic.  Removing that fixed the issue

```
one:
  state_user: administrator
```

Also a ‍♂️ moment for the `complete_user` - needs to be:

```
one:
  state_user: administrator
  completed_user: operator # NOT complete_user
```

Hope this helps someone else down the road.